# Not getting the approach in a minimization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, minimization

Recently, I was trying to solve this [dynamic programing problem](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/868/F), but somehow not getting the approach to solve it.

The editorial to the problem seems very confusing too and i would understand how to think properly to approach this problem.

Thanks.

### The problem

**F. Yet Another Minimization Problem**: Time limit per test: 2 seconds |
Memory limit per test: 256 megabytes |
Input: standard input |
Output: standard output

You are given an array of n integers `a1... an`. The cost of a subsegment is the number of unordered pairs of distinct indices within the subsegment that contain equal elements. Split the given array into `k` non-intersecting non-empty subsegments so that the sum of their costs is minimum possible. Each element should be present in exactly one subsegment.

**Input**

The first line contains two integers `n` and `k (2 ≤ n ≤ 105, 2 ≤ k ≤ min (n, 20))` - the length of the array and the number of segments you need to split the array into.

The next line contains `n` integers `a1, a2, ..., an (1 ≤ ai ≤ n)` - the elements of the array.

**Output**

Print single integer: the minimum possible total cost of resulting subsegments.

**Example 1**

```
input
7 3
1 1 3 3 3 2 1
output
1
```

**Example 2**

```
input
10 2
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
output
8
```

**Example 3**

```
input
13 3
1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1
output
9
```

**Note:**

In the first example it's optimal to split the sequence into the following three subsegments: `[1], [1, 3], [3, 3, 2, 1]`. The costs are `0, 0` and `1`, thus the answer is 1.

In the second example it's optimal to split the sequence in two equal halves. The cost for each half is `4`.

In the third example it's optimal to split the sequence in the following way: `[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 1]`. The costs are `4, 4, 1`.

Comment: Please, write the problem in the question in case the link becomes broken in the future.

Comment: Please, look at my answer to know if it is correct :-)

Answer (score 2):

### Understanding the problem

You just need to count the number of pairs in the serie of numbers (line 2) divised by `k` (line 1, second number)

**From the example 2:**

```
10 2 
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2

[numbers length] [divider]
[serie of numbers]
```

Take a look about the serie of numbers:
`1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2`

You need to divide by 2 the serie as an minimum total cost by pairs
`[1,2,1,2,1] [2,1,2,1,2]`

Then count the numbers of pairs for each number:

```
[1,2,1,2,1]
1 => [2,1,2,1] = 2 pairs
2 => [1,2,1] = 1 pair
1 => [2,1] = 1 pair
2 => [1] = 0
1 => [] = 0
Sum = 4 pairs

[2,1,2,1,2]
2 => [1,2,1,2] = 2 pairs
1 => [2,1,2] = 1 pairs
2 => [1,2] = 1 pairs
1 => [2] = 0
2 => [] = 0
Sum = 4 pairs

Total = 8
```

---

### How to find the best segment cost (Finally wrong..)

**This method is totally experimental and seems to be correct (but could be totally wrong too ... for now i tested some series and it worked)**

I took an other example:

```
10 3
7 7 2 4 6 9 7 4 1 1
```

**Subsegment 1:** I count the number of pairs in all the serie, then i sum each paired value by her key in the array (starting to **0**), divide this result by the number of pairs, then round (ceil?) at the closest integrer to find the position (which starting to **1**).

[image]

**Subsegment 2 and 3:** I do exactly the same but i excluded the first sub segment.

[image]

**Total:** `[7,7,2,4,6,9] [7,4,1] [1] = 1 + 0 + 0 = 1`

---

### Testing

I did a little script to generate random values relative to the problem:

```js
var n = document.getElementById('n')
var k = document.getElementById('k')
var s = document.getElementById('s')
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')

// apply random values
function random() {
  n.value = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (Math.random()*20)+2)
  k.value = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (n.value/3)+1)
  var serie = []
  for(var i = 0; i<n.value; i++){
    serie.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * (n.value-1)))
  }
  s.value = serie.join(' ')
}

window.onload = function() { random() }
btn.onclick = function() { random() }
```

```html
<input id="n" size="2" value="14">
<input id="k" size="2" value="3">
<input id="s" size="40">
<button id="btn">Random</button>
```

Hope it will help.